# Finding the expected value of a random variable by simulating a Markov process

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Suppose we have a pmf $\pi=\{\pi_1,\pi_2,...\}$ and a random variable $X$ such that $P(X=1)=\pi_1, P(X=2)=\pi_2,...$. I want to know how we can estimate $E(X)$. One way I know is (this is probably not very accurate) to simulate a MC $X_1,X_2,....$ and then $$E(X)\approx\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_i}{n}$$ Maybe I am no explaining this quite well but I looking for a better explanation of how this estimation can be done by simulating a MC. Also, can anyone provide a reference where I can learn this better?

Comment: Are you looking for code, some theorems, *and* general resources/tutorials? Could you narrow it down a bit? If not, there's plenty of things that pop up when you search for "Markov chain ergodic theorem."